# Using bootstrap-slider and bootstrap-switch in wordpress admin panel

Tags: jquery, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a Wordpress theme with an admin panel and I would like to put bootstrap switch and bootstrap sliders like:

[image] OR the switch button

But the problem is that I find the scripts in the page correctly added but nothing happen. I have the scripts enqueued like this:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts');
function load_admin_scripts( $hook ){

if($hook == 'toplevel_page_boon_theme'){
        //Slider
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider/bootstrap-slider.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

    }
}
```

In the files of the page I find correctly this scripts but when I try to slide nothing happens.

I have the input like this:

```
<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
```

And in the javascript I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Slider Bootstrap header
    $("#ex6").slider();
});
```

It creates inside the input a span like this:

[image]

But the input that I show is an usual input:

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I know it can be possible because I have shown in another themes.

Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: Come on! Some help?